# Play! framework project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, playframework, intellij-idea

I try to create project as it is said in tutorial - `play new myproject` -> `Java project`
Then I open it with `IntelliJ` and the `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/routes` file is all in errors. It cannot resolve nor `package` nor `RverseAssets`.
I didn't mind it until I needed to add some dependencies to my project. My `Build.scala` file could not be compiled. By the way, I had to create this file manually, it wasn't created for me.
I have `Play 2.0 Support` and `Playframework support` plugins installed.

**EDIT** Forgot to mention. I run command `idea` from the project root folder once it was generated

Comment: Did you run `play idea` to generate the IntelliJ project structure?

Comment: Yes! Forgot to mention it

Comment: Are you saying that Intellij doesn't recognize something like: `routes.ref.YourController.yourAction`?

Answer (score 3):

`play idea` marks wrong folders as Sources Roots. Unfold target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main in Project View. As you can see, `controllers` and `views` are marked as a `Sources Root`. Right-click on each and choose `Mark Directory As/Unmark As Sources Root`. Then right-click on `main` folder and choose `Mark Directory As/Generated Sources Root`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all well described how to create a new project and open it in IDEA 
[a documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE)

You must use a console play: 
idea with-sources=yes
Later the project already open in IDEA